# javascript groupby key and print in table

Tags: javascript, json

I have Client ID and gender.
below shown are the json response and as well javascript func to print the table.
the json response looks like this

```
studies = [{
    "id": {
        "Value": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    "gen": {
        "sex": "M"
    }
} ,
{
    "id": {
        "Value": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    "gen": {
        "sex": "M"
    }
} ,
{
      "id": {
        "Value": [
            "1"
        ]
      },  
      "gen": {
        "sex": "M"
    }
},
{
    "id": {
        "Value": [
            "2"
        ]
    },
    "gen": {
        "sex": "F"
    }
} 
 ]
```

javascript func to print the table

```
function () {
                var studies  = JSON.parse(this.responseText);            
                var table = createTable([ "ID", "Gender"]);

                // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
                for (var i = 0; i < studies.length; ++i) {
                    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
                    var study = studies[i];
                    tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML  = study["id"].Value[0];
                    tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML  = study[""gen]["sex"];
                }

                var divContainer = document.getElementById("employee list");
                divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                divContainer.appendChild(table);
            }
```

current table looks like this
[image: Current table]

Question:
I am trying to group using ID and print the table //result -> 2 rows with ID 1 & 2

which method to use // reduce func will create an object but here in my case, i dont want to create new obj and then print in table.

confused! any help appreciated!

Comment: Did I get the question wrong, what happens if there is a 2nd female with id `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the id of elements that are already displayed in an array.

```
function () {
    var studies  = JSON.parse(this.responseText);            
    var table = createTable([ "ID", "Gender"]);

    var ids = [];
    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < studies.length; ++i) {
        var study = studies[i];
        if (!ids.includes(study["id"].Value[0])) {
            ids.push(study["id"].Value[0])
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML  = study["id"].Value[0];
            tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML  = study["gen"]["sex"];
        }
    }

    var divContainer = document.getElementById("employee list");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table); }
```

Comment: This is the same answer as mine. Why is not mine accepted as best answer as it is posted before this answer?

Comment: yours doesn't work because you are referring study before declaring it. so my answer is correct.

Comment: @VasiMaruseac FYI: the "green hook" only represents the "accepted answer". The questioner can accept any answer as the correct answer no matter if the code works or if someone answered before or after another one. To verify the "best" answer it's more accurate to look at the upvotes. (Mostly the accepted answer is the best, but as I mentioned, this only depends on the questioner)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you keep an array of used ids

```
function () {
                var studies  = JSON.parse(this.responseText);            
                var table = createTable([ "ID", "Gender"]);
                const arrIds = []
                // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
                for (var i = 0; i < studies.length; ++i) {
                    var study = studies[i];
                    if(!arrIds.includes(study["id"].Value[0])){
                       tr = table.insertRow(-1);
                       tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML  = study["id"].Value[0];
                       tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML  = study[""gen]["sex"];
                       arrIds.push(study["id"].Value[0]);
                    }
                }

                var divContainer = document.getElementById("employee list");
                divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                divContainer.appendChild(table);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of what you have, (you iterate over all rows)

```js
var studies  = studies = [{"id": {"Value": ["1"]},"gen": {"sex": "M"}} ,{"id": {"Value": ["1"]},"gen": {"sex": "M"}} ,{"id": {"Value": ["1"]},  "gen": {"sex": "M"}},{"id": {"Value": ["2"]},"gen": {"sex": "F"}}];       


for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(studies)) {
  console.log(`${values.id.Value}, ${values.gen.sex}`);
}
```

If you want to print each row per `id` and `gender` you will have to store those two values and then compare if already printed. Something like:

```js
var studies  = studies = [{"id": {"Value": ["1"]},"gen": {"sex": "M"}} ,{"id": {"Value": ["1"]},"gen": {"sex": "M"}} ,{"id": {"Value": ["1"]},  "gen": {"sex": "M"}},{"id": {"Value": ["2"]},"gen": {"sex": "F"}}];       


var alreadyPrinted = {'M' : [], 'F': []};

for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(studies)) {
  if(alreadyPrinted[values.gen.sex].includes(values.id.Value[0])) {
    continue;
  }
  
  alreadyPrinted[values.gen.sex].push(values.id.Value[0])
  console.log(`${values.id.Value[0]}, ${values.gen.sex}`);
}
```